# Computing all values or stopping and returning just the best value if found

Tags: list, scala, dictionary, stream

I have a list of items and for each item I am computing a value. Computing this value is a bit computationally intensive so I want to minimise it as much as possible.

The algorithm I need to implement is this:

1. I have a value X
2. For each item

   a. compute the value for it, if it is < 0 ignore it completely

   b. if (value > 0) && (value < X)
         return pair (item, value)
3. Return all (item, value) pairs in a List (that have the value > 0), ideally sorted by value

To make it a bit clearer, step 3 only happens if none of the items have a value less than X. In step 2, when we encounter the first item that is less than X we should not compute the rest and just return that item (we can obviously return it in a Set() by itself to match the return type).

The code I have at the moment is as follows:

```
  val itemValMap = items.foldLeft(Map[Item, Int)]()) {
  (map : Map[Item, Int], key : Item) =>
    val value = computeValue(item)
    if ( value >= 0 )        //we filter out negative ones
      map + (key -> value)
    else
      map
  }

 val bestItem = itemValMap.minBy(_._2)
 if (bestItem._2 < bestX)
 {
      List(bestItem)
 }
 else
 {
    itemValMap.toList.sortBy(_._2)
 }
```

However, what this code is doing is computing all the values in the list and choosing the best one, rather than stopping as a 'better' one is found. I suspect I have to use Streams in some way to achieve this?

Comment: For the record both solutions by Patryk Ćwiek and Régis Jean-Gilles worked fine. For some reason in my scenario the chosen answer performed a little bit better, but this could be down to my implementation of the rest of the program, or to how `Stream` does its internal magic (I didn't test both in isolation). Unfortunately I could only choose one answer. If you are looking for a similar solution try both and see which works best in your scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I'm not sure how your whole setup looks like, but I tried to prepare a minimal example that would mirror your situation.

Here it is then:

```
object StreamTest {
  case class Item(value : Int)
  def createItems() = List(Item(0),Item(3),Item(30),Item(8),Item(8),Item(4),Item(54),Item(-1),Item(23),Item(131))
  def computeValue(i : Item) = { Thread.sleep(3000); i.value * 2 - 2 }

  def process(minValue : Int)(items : Seq[Item]) = {
    val stream = Stream(items: _*).map(item => item -> computeValue(item)).filter(tuple => tuple._2 >= 0)
    stream.find(tuple => tuple._2 < minValue).map(List(_)).getOrElse(stream.sortBy(_._2).toList)
  }
}
```

Each calculation takes 3 seconds. Now let's see how it works:

```
val items = StreamTest.createItems()
val result = StreamTest.process(2)(items)
result.foreach(r => println("Original: " + r._1 + " , calculated: " + r._2))
```

Gives:

```
[info] Running Main 
Original: Item(3) , calculated: 4
Original: Item(4) , calculated: 6
Original: Item(8) , calculated: 14
Original: Item(8) , calculated: 14
Original: Item(23) , calculated: 44
Original: Item(30) , calculated: 58
Original: Item(54) , calculated: 106
Original: Item(131) , calculated: 260
[success] Total time: 31 s, completed 2013-11-21 15:57:54
```

Since there's no value smaller than 2, we got a list ordered by the calculated value. Notice that two pairs are missing, because calculated values are smaller than 0 and got filtered out.

OK, now let's try with a different minimum cut-off point:

```
val result = StreamTest.process(5)(items)
```

Which gives:

```
[info] Running Main 
Original: Item(3) , calculated: 4
[success] Total time: 7 s, completed 2013-11-21 15:55:20
```

Good, it returned a list with only one item, the first value (second item in the original list) that was smaller than 'minimal' value and **was not smaller than 0.**

I hope that the example above is easily adaptable to your needs...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Would you mind explaining a little more what's actually happening with the first and second line of the `process` function? I just want to make sure that I don't create intermediate collections which have items with value < 0 (which was the reason of my `foldLeft` instead of `filter`, to drop the item as soon as possible), does the stream anyway avoid this? Also, does the `find` work lazily, as in it stops as soon as it finds one, but the actual `computeValue` inside the map is only computed as the stream gets the next item?

Comment: @jbx Well, `Stream` was designed to be lazy (and caching, and possibly infinite), so it *should* process the elements one-by-one instead of creating intermediate collections. Regarding your second question - yes, that's why my second run only took ~7 seconds (two calculations) instead of ~32 seconds (10 calculations, two discarded from the end result), if all entries were calculated anyway, both runs would have taken ~30 seconds.

Comment: It worked. It also seemed a little bit faster than the View solution, which also worked. Not sure why (or whether it is related to my implementation after all). I did a small edit to your code in your answer because I am filtering things out if they're smaller than 0 (not not-equal to 0). You might want to check if the output still matches or change the value from -10 to something positive (and removing the 0 items) so that it matches my question, for future people who might look at your answer.

Comment: @jbx I'm glad it works. I have changed the data and output in the answer to match new conditions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am still new to Scala, so this advanced concepts are a bit hard to come up with on my own until I get used to them.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to avoid the computation of unneeded values is to make your collection lazy by using the `view` method:

```
val weigthedItems = items.view.map{ i => i -> computeValue(i) }.filter(_._2 >= 0 )
weigthedItems.find(_._2 < X).map(List(_)).getOrElse(weigthedItems.sortBy(_._2))
```

By example here is a test in the REPL:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

type Item = String
def computeValue( item: Item ): Int = {
  println("Computing " + item)
  item.toInt
}
val items = List[Item]("13", "1", "5", "-7", "12", "3", "-1", "15")
val X = 10
val weigthedItems = items.view.map{ i => i -> computeValue(i) }.filter(_._2 >= 0 )
weigthedItems.find(_._2 < X).map(List(_)).getOrElse(weigthedItems.sortBy(_._2))

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

Computing 13
Computing 1
defined type alias Item
computeValue: (item: Item)Int
items: List[String] = List(13, 1, 5, -7, 12, 3, -1, 15)
X: Int = 10
weigthedItems: scala.collection.SeqView[(String, Int),Seq[_]] = SeqViewM(...)
res27: Seq[(String, Int)] = List((1,1))
```

As you can see computeValue was only called up to the first value < X (that is, up to `1`)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In my original code, I was using `foldLeft` instead of `filter` to avoid creating a collection twice, once with all the items and then a second one with the filtered items, since I might have lots of items which are `< 0`, which in both cases I do not need. Does the `view` do the same thing to the `filter`? Also can you explain the `getOrElse` part? Not sure why you used `weightedItems` in the `weightedItems.sortBy(_._2)`, its not filtered out from items with value < 0, or is it? I want to always return items with value >= 0 only, and eliminate them as early as possible.

Comment: If you always want to filter out negative values, just move the call to `filter` to the definition of `weigthedItems`. I have updated my answer to do just that.
The `getOrElse` is so that you just get the reuslt of `find` (if any), or else return the whole collection along with their value (which is exactly what `weigthedItems`already is, so I just return that).

Comment: Thanks, so just to make sure I am getting it. The fact that we are doing a `view` before the map makes it lazy? I.e. It will only compute the `computeValue` when the `find` starts looking for items, and consequently even the `filter` will lazily take out items that are not eligible (rather than creating a new map with the filtered items).

Comment: Thanks, both yours and the other solution by Patryk Ćwiek worked. For some reason using Stream was a bit faster, not sure why.

Comment: If that is indeed faster, you can keep the basically the same code and just dominor changes: replace `view` with `toStream` and `List(_)` with `Stream(_)`. Which gives: `val weigthedItems = items.toStream.map{ i => i -> computeValue(i) }.filter(_._2 >= 0 );
weigthedItems.find(_._2 < X).map(Stream(_)).getOrElse(weigthedItems.sortBy(_._2))`

Comment: Thanks I will try it just for the sake of the experiment. Any idea why the Stream might be faster?

Comment: Your latter suggestion seems substantially the same as his right?